# Layer OpacityEngineLayer was previously used as oldLayer. Flutter carousel_slider

Tags: android, flutter, slider

I am using carousel_slider library in my flutter application and if i scrool my screen to the end and if scroll back to the top where my flutter widget is present so its start throwing an exception and carousel_slider stops sliding and if i click anywhere on the screen  its starts working again please suggest me the solution for the same:

```
 ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
Layer OpacityEngineLayer was previously used as oldLayer.
Once a layer is used as oldLayer, it may not be used again. Instead, after calling one of the
SceneBuilder.push* methods and passing an oldLayer to it, use the layer returned by the method as
oldLayer in subsequent frames.
'dart:ui/compositing.dart':
Failed assertion: line 88 pos 9: '<optimized out>'

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md



 When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      _EngineLayerWrapper._debugCheckNotUsedAsOldLayer (dart:ui/compositing.dart:88:9)
#3      SceneBuilder.addRetained.<anonymous closure>.recursivelyCheckChildrenUsedOnce (dart:ui/compositing.dart:656:21)
#4      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:410:8)
#5      SceneBuilder.addRetained.<anonymous closure>.recursivelyCheckChildrenUsedOnce (dart:ui/compositing.dart:662:18)
#6      SceneBuilder.addRetained.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/compositing.dart:665:7)
#7      SceneBuilder.addRetained (dart:ui/compositing.dart:668:6)
#8      Layer._addToSceneWithRetainedRendering (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:543:15)
#9      ContainerLayer.addChildrenToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1106:13)
#10     ClipRectLayer.addToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1368:5)
#11     Layer._addToSceneWithRetainedRendering (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:546:5)
#12     ContainerLayer.addChildrenToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1106:13)
#13     OffsetLayer.addToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1240:5)
#14     Layer._addToSceneWithRetainedRendering (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:546:5)
#15     ContainerLayer.addChildrenToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1106:13)
#16     OffsetLayer.addToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1240:5)
#17     Layer._addToSceneWithRetainedRendering (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:546:5)
#18     ContainerLayer.addChildrenToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1106:13)
#19     OffsetLayer.addToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1240:5)
#20     Layer._addToSceneWithRetainedRendering (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:546:5)
#21     ContainerLayer.addChildrenToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1106:13)
#22     PhysicalModelLayer.addToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:2081:5)
#23     Layer._addToSceneWithRetainedRendering (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:546:5)
#24     ContainerLayer.addChildrenToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1106:13)
#25     PhysicalModelLayer.addToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:2081:5)
#26     Layer._addToSceneWithRetainedRendering (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:546:5)
#27     ContainerLayer.addChildrenToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1106:13)
#28     OffsetLayer.addToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1240:5)
#29     Layer._addToSceneWithRetainedRendering (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:546:5)
#30     ContainerLayer.addChildrenToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1106:13)
#31     OffsetLayer.addToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1240:5)
#32     Layer._addToSceneWithRetainedRendering (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:546:5)
#33     ContainerLayer.addChildrenToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1106:13)
#34     TransformLayer.addToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1681:5)
#35     ContainerLayer.buildScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:938:5)
#36     RenderView.compositeFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:226:37)
#37     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:501:18)
#38     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#39     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#40     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1145:15)
#41     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#42     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:996:5)
#46     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:150:10)
#47     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:270:5)
#48     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:114:31)
(elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and dart:async)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: Layer OpacityEngineLayer was previously used as oldLayer.

Another exception was thrown: Layer OpacityEngineLayer was previously used as oldLayer



class _CarouselState extends State<Carousel> {
```

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
print("Build crausel called");
return Container(
color: Colors.white,
padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
child: new CarouselSlider(
items: [
Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
image: DecorationImage(
image: AssetImage("assets/onboarding_shape_.png"),
fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
),
),

```
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/onboarding_shape_.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/onboarding_shape_.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/onboarding_shape_.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/onboarding_shape_.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      options: CarouselOptions(
          height: 200.0,
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          autoPlay: true,
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          enableInfiniteScroll: true,
          autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
          viewportFraction: 0.9,
          pauseAutoPlayOnManualNavigate: true),
    ));
```

}
}

Comment: A friendly tip, you are more likely to get good answers if you post the relevant code here as well

Answer (score 3):

To fix this issue, simply restart your app